# Can't save state in React while POST API request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, request

I have handleSubmit function that send two POST request, one for img upload and one for other information. I want to take the response from the img upload request and take the 'filename' and then store it in state so I can sent it with the other POST request.

Here is my Request Options

```
const postOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.serviceToken}`
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        p_emp_id: empId,
        p_pr_doc_type: docType,
        p_from_date: fromDate,
        p_to_date: toDate,
        p_doc_number: docNumber,
        p_addres: address,
        p_addres_en: addressEN,
        p_doc_store: docPath,
        p_creator_id: creator,
        p_org_id: org
    })
};
```

Then here is my Handle Submit function

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', selectedFiles);
    await fetch(`${config.apiHost}single/`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data
    })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((img) => setDocPath(img.filename))
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.message);
        });
    setEditOpen(false);
    fetch(`${config.apiHost}api/employees/info/pr_docs/new/`, postOptions);
    console.log(postOptions.body);
};
```

My state `docPath` stays empty while I'm trying to submit so after that I can't see it in my request.

Comment: what state here stays empty??

`docPath` ?

Comment: @cerebralFart is `fetch(`${config.apiHost}api/employees/info/pr_docs/new/`, postOptions);` the fetch requests that takes the file you set?

Comment: and also @todevmilen i didnt see you adding the file to the `postOptions` variable

Comment: @GiftEnyoghasim, I don't know, I'm not the OP, I merely did some formatting of the question

Comment: ok @CerebralFart

Comment: @GiftEnyoghasim The state that is not added is  `docPath`, this request takes the file `fetch(`${config.apiHost}single/``  and I want to add only the `filename` not the entire file in the `postOptions`

Comment: ok you want to add the file name to `postOptions` after the first request right???

Comment: soo what is the key value you want to use to store the filename in the `postOptions` object?

Comment: @GiftEnyoghasim , Yes I want to add it there so I can send it with the request `fetch(${config.apiHost}api/employees/info/pr_docs/new/ ` to my DB

Comment: `p_doc_store: docPath`

Comment: please i will post an answer now since the comment has limits.

Comment: you can check my answer and see if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can refactor your code to this and lets see if it works;

```
let postOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.serviceToken}`
    },
    body: {
        p_emp_id: empId,
        p_pr_doc_type: docType,
        p_from_date: fromDate,
        p_to_date: toDate,
        p_doc_number: docNumber,
        p_addres: address,
        p_addres_en: addressEN,
        p_creator_id: creator,
        p_org_id: org
    }
};
```

for the handle submit it can be

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', selectedFiles);
    await fetch(`${config.apiHost}single/`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data
    })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((img) => {
const postOptionsBody = {...postOptions.body, p_doc_store : img.filename }

postOptions = {...postOptions, body : JSON.stringify(postOptionsBody) }
setDocPath(img.filename)
})
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.message);
        });
    setEditOpen(false);
    fetch(`${config.apiHost}api/employees/info/pr_docs/new/`, postOptions);
    console.log(postOptions.body);
};
```

Comment: no problem man 